# undefined method `ingredients_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fdbfd71c3d0>:0x007fdbf94bea60>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

The scenario is I am creating a recipe app. Where you have your initial recipe model and since you can have more than one ingredient I have a separate ingredient model that I am trying to nest inside of the recipe form.

```
    class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :Catagory
        has_many :ingredients
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients

        scope :visible, lambda { where(:visible => true) }
        scope :invisible, lambda { where(:visible => false) }
        scope :sorted, lambda { order("recipes.position ASC") }
        scope :newest_first, lambda { order("recipes.created_at DESC")}
        scope :search, lambda {|query|
        where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])
        }
     end
```

ingredient model:

```
    class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
         belongs_to :recipe
    end
```

recipe controller:

```
    class RecipeController < ApplicationController
      def index
         @recipes = Recipe.sorted
      end

      def new
         @recipe = Recipe.new({:name => "Default"})
         @recipe_count = Recipe.count + 1
         @ingredient = Ingredient.new({:name => "Enter Ingredient"})
      end

      def create
         @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
         if @recipe.save
            flash[:notice] = 'You have successfully created a new recipe!'
            redirect_to(:action => 'index')
         else
            @recipe_count = Recipe.count + 1
            render('new')
         end
      end

      def edit
         @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
        @recipe_count = Recipe.count
      end

     def update
        @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
        if @recipe.update_attributes(recipe_params)
           flash[:notice] = 'Your changes have been saved!'
           redirect_to(:action => 'index')
        else
           @recipe_count = Recipe.count
           render('edit')
        end
     end

    def delete
       @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    end

    def destroy
      @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id]).destroy
      flash[:notice] = 'Your recipe has been deleted'
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    end

    private
      def recipe_params
         params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :position, :ingredient, :directions, :created_at)
      end
    end
```

recipe form:

```
    <table summary="Recipe form fields">
      <tr>
        <th><%= f.label(:name, "Recipe Name") %></th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><%= f.label(:position) %></th>
        <td><%= f.select(:position, 1..@recipe_count) %></td>
      </tr>
      <%= form_for @ingredient do |f| %>
         <th><%= f.label(:position) %></th>
         <td><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
      <% end %>
      <tr>
         <th><%= f.label(:directions) %></th>
         <td><%= text_area_tag(:message, "Be specific", size: "50x30") %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

and I am getting this error:
undefined method `ingredients_path' for #<#:0x007fdbf94bea60>

Comment: Whats the output of `rake path` command

Comment: I got:
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'path'

--I have never used that command before I just typed 'rake path' in the root of my app. @AntarrByrd

Comment: Sorry i meant rake routes

Comment: `Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
       GET|POST /:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format) :controller#:action` @AntarrByrd

Answer (score 0):

**Scopes**

Firstly, your scope syntax is incorrect:

```
#app/models/recipe.rb
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :catagory #-> should always be lower case
   has_many :ingredients
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients

   scope :visible,      -> { where(:visible => true) }
   scope :invisible,    -> { where(:visible => false) }
   scope :sorted,       -> { order("recipes.position ASC") }
   scope :newest_first, -> { order("recipes.created_at DESC")}
   scope :search, ->(query) { where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])}
end
```

You'll be better using the [`scopes` documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to determine the syntax

---

**Form**

Secondly, your form & supporting `controller` code is incorrect

To affect a nested form, you'll be best doing the following:

```
#app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @recipe = Recipe.new
      @recipe.ingredients.build
   end

   def create
      @recipe = Recipe.new recipe_params
   end

   private

   def recipe_params
       params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :position, ingredients_attributes: [:name])
   end
end

#app/views/recipes/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field(:name) %>
   <%= f.select(:position, 1..@recipe_count) %>

   <%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |i| %>
      <%= i.text_field :name %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will give you the ability to pass the attributes you require through the "parent" form. The problem you have is that you're trying to embed a form within a form

You'll see how to achieve what you're looking for with [this documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

---

**Fix**

You'll be able to remedy your issue by only using a single form

The path error will come from your embedded form (for `@ingredient`), and will likely be resolved by removing the reference to this from your view (as above)

Comment: I've corrected the code as you have describes and it is as if it isn't recognizing the @recipe because I am getting this error now:undefined method `recipes_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fcbf799ba90>:0x007fcbf799a7f8>